# Angular UI - Kendo - Filter not working for dynamic column

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, angular11

I am working on a kendo grid in angular and binding dynamic columns. Filters are working fine for normal columns but not for dynamic columns.

For understanding I have created a small demo application. You can find the same,
[Filter not working for dynamic column stackblitz demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckztcy-xh6xv7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

In the demo app, **name** is normal column and filter working for it but **Term** and **Semester**
are the columns whose values are generated dynamically and filter not working.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcY82.png)

Solution and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

[Note]- This is a sample project with dummy data

Answer (score 1):

It was fixed.
Filtering and sorting by dynamically created columns works correctly.

environment:
angular/core: 13.3.9
progress/kendo-angular-grid: 7.0.1

Working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rkc74f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts